# Rails Webpacker SCRIPT5009: 'app' is undefined - IE11 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

For some reason most of my JS work in IE11 and lower fails. No issues with Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

I have in the application.html.slim file:

```
meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge'
```

I found this: [github webpacker thread](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1235)

So I went through and tried the following in my config > webpack > production.js:

```
if (environment.plugins.getIndex('UglifyJs') !== -1) {
  const plugin = environment.plugins.get('UglifyJs');
  plugin.options.uglifyOptions.ecma = 5;
}

environment.config.optimization.minimizer[0].options.uglifyOptions.ecma = undefined

environment.plugins.get("UglifyJs").options.uglifyOptions.ecma = 5
```

None of those worked. In the console I'm getting:

> SCRIPT5009: 'app' is undefined

From my home page I have it set up:

```
= content_for :head do
  = stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles/home'
  = javascript_pack_tag 'home'
  = javascript_include_tag "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['MAP_KEY']}"
= content_for :body do
 .container
  .row
   #map-banner.banner[type"hidden" data-location=all_locations.to_json]
 =render template: '/layouts/application'
javascript:
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.home);
```

Then in my javascript > packs > home.js

```
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';
app.home = () => {
  function init() {
    setupSlider();
    homeSlider();
    startGoogleMap();
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('a.tab');
    for (let tab of tabs) {
      tab.addEventListener('click', tabClicked);
    }
    document
      .querySelector('#region-select_')
      .addEventListener('change', selectClicked);
  }
return init();
};
```

Current versions:

- webpack 3.12.0
- rails 5.2.2
- yarn 1.17.3
- bootstrap 4.3.1

When I checked in the Network on my tiny-slider.js it's returning a status code of 304 however its returning 200 in Chrome. Any idea why it's not compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here in case someone finds it useful. Updated config > webpack > environment.js with:

```
environment.loaders.get('babel').exclude = [];
```